# How do I parse a file and substitute the environment variables with values in Python

Tags: python, shell

I have a text file (lets call it file1.txt), it contains the following lines:
"read model $path_1"

How do I replace the value of path_1 variable in this text file and write it to another file (lets call it file2.txt) with same contents but $path_1 variable expanded. My file2.txt should contain something like the following:
"read model /home/Aero/test"

Is there any parser in python available to do this job? I looked into ConfigParser module but looks to me that it needs a config file with variable=value pair.

Regards,
Sandhya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

string.Template

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template('$who likes $what')
>>> s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
'tim likes kung pao'
```

Answer (score 4):

[`os.path.expandvars()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars)

Comment: This works. Thank you. But is there a way to make it work for even shell variables, say I set some variable $path_1=/home/Aero/test in the shell, but using os.path.expandvars("path_1") doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe because you are setting shell (bash) variables, and not environment variables, @Sandhya. Try using `EXPORT` or `SET` http://nixcraft.com/shell-scripting/759-linux-set-environment-variables-my-shell.html